# Read File directly from HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is there a way to read any file format from HDFS directly by using the HDFS path, instead of having to pull the file locally from HDFS and read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pull the entire file. Whether you use `cat` or `text` commands, the entire file is still being streamed to your shell. There's just no remnant of the file when the command ends. So, if you plan on inspecting the file a few times, it's better to `get` it

As an hdfs client, you must contact the namenode to acquire all block locations for a particular file.

Comment: marked as answer as it compliments all the other answers

Answer (score 6):

You can use `cat` command on HDFS to read regular text files.

```
hdfs dfs -cat /path/to/file.csv
```

To read compressed files like `gz, bz2` etc, you can use:

```
hdfs dfs -text /path/to/file.gz
```

These are the two read methods that Hadoop supports natively using `FsShell` comamnds. For other complex file types, you will have to use a more complex way, like, a Java program or something along those lines.

Answer (score 4):

hdfs dfs -cat /path or hadoop fs -cat /path

Answer (score 2):

You can try with hdfs dfs -cat

Usage: hdfs dfs -cat [-ignoreCrc] URI [URI ...]

```
hdfs dfs -cat /your/path
```